# How to write sql query to select a column with space in column name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with column like this  `id, email, phone, first name, last name`
I want to select phone corresponding to a particular email like this

```
Select phone from customer_tbl where email='testfinal@gmail.com';
```

this is working but if do something simailar for `first name` than it is not working, now the issue is due to space in column name.

```
Select first name from customer_tbl where email='testfinal@gmail.com';
```

It is giving below error.

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'first' in 'field list'

Comment: For the sake of your sanity, don't have spaces in table/column identifiers

Comment: Make your life easier, use underscore instead of space in column names.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select `first name` from customer_tbl where email='testfinal@gmail.com';
```

add the ``